# XText - get content (compiled value) of XExpression

Tags: xtext

I have a certain part of my XText grammer that defines a block for classes that shall print all its expressions. The XText grammar part for this looks as follows:

```
Print: 
    {Print}
    'print' '{' 
        print += PrintLine* 
    '}';
PrintLine:
    obj += XExpression;
```

Now I use the following inferrer code to create a print() method:

```
Print: {
    members += feature.toMethod('print', typeRef(void)) [
    body = '''
        «FOR printline : feature.print»
            System.out.println(«printline.obj»);
        «ENDFOR»
        '''
    ]
}
```

Ok, I go ahead and test it with the following code in a class:

```
print {
    "hallo"
    4
    6 + 7
}
```

And the result is the following:

```
public void print() {
   System.out.println([org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.impl.XStringLiteralImpl@20196ba8 (value: hallo)]);
   System.out.println([org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.impl.XNumberLiteralImpl@7d0b0f7d (value: 4)]);
   System.out.println([<XNumberLiteralImpl> + <XNumberLiteralImpl>]);}
```

Of course, I was hoping for:

```
public void print() {
   System.out.println("hallo");
   System.out.println(4);
   System.out.println(6+7);
}
```

I understand that I might have to call the compiler somehow in the inferrer for `«printline.obj»`, but I am really not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are doing this on a wrong basis. this sounds to me like an extension of xbase, not only a simple use.

```
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase

Print: 
    {Print}
    'print' 
        print=XPrintBlock
    ;

XPrintBlock returns xbase::XBlockExpression:
    {xbase::XBlockExpression}'{'
        expressions+=XPrintLine*
    '}'
;

XPrintLine returns xbase::XExpression:
    {PrintLine} obj=XExpression

;
```

Type Computer

```
class MyDslTypeComputer extends XbaseTypeComputer {

     def dispatch computeTypes(XPrintLine literal, ITypeComputationState state) {
        state.withNonVoidExpectation.computeTypes(literal.obj)
        state.acceptActualType(getPrimitiveVoid(state))
    }

}
```

Compiler

```
class MyDslXbaseCompiler extends XbaseCompiler {

    override protected doInternalToJavaStatement(XExpression obj, ITreeAppendable appendable, boolean isReferenced) {
        if (obj instanceof XPrintLine) {
            appendable.trace(obj)
            appendable.append("System.out.println(")
            internalToJavaExpression(obj.obj,appendable);
            appendable.append(");")
            appendable.newLine
            return
        }

        super.doInternalToJavaStatement(obj, appendable, isReferenced)
    }

}
```

XExpressionHelper

```
class MyDslXExpressionHelper extends XExpressionHelper {

    override hasSideEffects(XExpression expr) {
        if (expr instanceof XPrintLine || expr.eContainer instanceof XPrintLine) {
            return true
        }
        super.hasSideEffects(expr)
    }

}
```

JvmModelInferrer

```
def dispatch void infer(Print print, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
    acceptor.accept(
        print.toClass("a.b.C") [
            members+=print.toMethod("demo", Void.TYPE.typeRef) [
                body = print.print
            ]
        ]

    )
}
```

Bindings

```
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    def Class<? extends ITypeComputer> bindITypeComputer() {
        MyDslTypeComputer
    }

    def Class<? extends XbaseCompiler> bindXbaseCompiler() {
        MyDslXbaseCompiler
    }

    def Class<? extends XExpressionHelper> bindXExpressionHelper() {
        MyDslXExpressionHelper
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Christian, thats just what I needed! Thanks for this awesome Xmas gift :)

Comment: Hi Christian, I just encountered one problem with this solution. When I use the "<=" comparator, something goes wrong. That means when I use for instance "print { 4 <= 5 }", I get an error that says "no viable alternative at input '<='". This is strange because all other comparators work fine.

Comment: are you sure xbase lib is on the classpath of the model project?

Comment: Hi Christian, I was using your code in a bigger project in a different context with a much more complex grammar, etc. I just came up with the PrintLine example as a form of abstraction. Now I reimplemented your solution to better under what is happening and there is a weird behaviour: anytime the XPrintLine is a single expression like 4 or "hello", everything works fine. If for instance is an addition like 4 + 5 (or any other operation), the XText editor is complaining that 'The method +(int) is undefined'. Do you have an idea what is happening here? Yes, the xbase lib is on the classpath.

Comment: can you share a complete sample project based on my grammar

Comment: Many thanks for the help so far. I uploaded the projects (base, sdk, tests, ui) to https://github.com/lukasiewycz/lukasiewycz.github.io/raw/master/exchange/2016-01-12-stackoverflow-mydsl.zip .

Comment: i miss the project that contains the sample model

Comment: I uploaded the sample model here: https://github.com/lukasiewycz/lukasiewycz.github.io/raw/master/exchange/2016-01-12-stackoverflow-testmydsl.zip . In this moment, I realized that I should add the xtend libraries to the classpath in the sample model project, and now it works! I wonder why I suddenly need xtend when I have a binary operation and why xtend is not automatically included when the code generation is triggered? In the other project, I still have the issue that "<=" is not working, but now I can try to narrow this problem down. Thanks.

Comment: xbase lib is sufficient. it contains the implentations for + - and all the other operators

Comment: Finally, I could reproduce a minimal example of the '<=' issue: you just need to extend the grammar here the following way: Print: {Print} 'print' ('<=')? body=(XPrintBlock);. That means we add an '<=' anywhere as a part of the grammar (here for the sake of simplicity after the print word). Then the model project is complaining that "no viable alternative at input '<='" for all usages of '<=' in the print block. It is weird because this happens only for '<=' and not for '>=' or '>', etc. Can you reproduce that behaviour?

Comment: xbase uses ```OpCompare: '>=' | '<' '=' | '>' | '<' ;``` => if you define '<=' as keyword it will never detect '<''='. so what about changing your grammar to '<''='

Comment: Ok, thats it. I guess there must be a reason for this confusing inconsistency in xbase. But that also means that I can write "<   =" which I dont want as it always should look like "<=". I see that xtend gets this right somehow, forbidding "<  =" somewhere (xtend shows a different error message when you use "<  =" and ">  =", thats quite clear now). Can you give me a hint where I could start looking to see how "<  =" is forbidden in xtend?

Comment: i dont get that point. the antlr lexer is greedy. it will never lex '<''=' if it can lex '<=' which you allow by your grammar. xtend does not forbid it but operatormapping cannot map it and thus cannot find a method it references to

Comment: First point I do not understand is why OpCompare in xbase is defined the way it is. Why not simply `OpCompare: '>=' | '<=' | '>' | '<' ;` ? The other point I was raising is the issue that now whitespaces (ok, these were not that obvious in my previous comment) are allowed between the '<' and '=' in my model if I define `<=` as `'<' '='`. However, it is obvious that I do not want to have these whitespaces which are somehow not allowed in xtend that is based on xbase.

Comment: Since I am not a committer I cannot tell